# What would be a better way to check if a number is prime?

Tags: c++, math, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if an int is prime more efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777509/checking-if-an-int-is-prime-more-efficiently)

```
bool isPrime(int num)
{
    for(int i = 2; i <= (num/2)+1; i++)
    {
        if(num % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've looked on Wikipedia, but I don't understand any of the fast primality tests it describes.

Comment: Other than the simple errors in your algorithm noted below, the "better" ways are much more complex. Mathematicians have studied prime numbers for centuries.

Comment: @Kirill: read the other question before marking as dupe, that question is about finding a prime with certain characteristics (i.e. many numbers must be tested).  I do believe this question has been asked before, but that isn't it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, you only need to iterate while `i * i <= num`.

After that, you might notice that testing whether a number is a multiple of 2 is just a bit test.  Once you know the number isn't even, you know there are no even factors, so you can skip testing them.

That leads to:

```
bool isPrime(int num)
{
    if (num < 4) return true;
    if (~num & 1) return false;
    for( int i = 3; i * i <= num; i += 2 )
    {
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about `if (~num & 1) return false;`

Comment: @Martin: Pretty sure.  Even numbers not less than four are not prime.  Do you have a case it fails for?

Comment: Maybe you should add `if (num < 1) return false;` because, IIRC, prime numbers are by definition greater than 1.

Comment: @Seth: I'm providing the same result as the question for those.  (And it would be `if (num < 2)`)  Anyway, `0` and `1` may not be prime but they aren't composite either.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: No. Just trying to work out what it meant.

Comment: @Martin: It returns false for even numbers.  If `num` is even, then the LSB is 0, and `~num` LSB is 1.

Comment: @Ben: You should be taking an unsigned int rather than an int as an argument. *Primality* is a feature of natural numbers (1,2,3,...), not the integers. Zero is not a natural number, so 0 is not prime. Neither is one prime. The first prime number is 2.

Comment: @David: Sorry, the signature in the question is `bool isPrime(int)`.  If there was a good reason to change the signature, I would, but this is just gratuitous nit-picking.  Like I said, `0` and `1` may not be prime, but neither are they composite.  Without a more complete specification for the function, it's hard to determine the correct behavior.  Based on the code provided, it appears that the specification is "return `false` if `num` is composite, and `true` otherwise".

Comment: Given that signature, the correct answer is `if (num < 2) return false;` You are the one picking nits by reading IsPrime as IsNotComposite. That 1 is not prime is a very important concept.

Answer (score 1):

If your input set is particular small, then you can have a step where in you construct the primes using [sieve of erathones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and then do a primality test on that sieve. This is the next step after your algorithm.

There are many performance tweaks that you can make for faster primality testing, like skipping the factors of 2 and 3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

The better way(if you want speed up your application) is pre-calculate at first prime numbers, add them into array and just search your number in it, or check division on array elements.

Also you can check `num % i == 0` not upto `num/2`, but up to `sqrt(num)`.

PS:

```
if(num % i == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

You must return false:)

Answer (score 0):

For something faster than your approach, you should build a primes table using Sieve of Eratosthenes or the like (generate primes at least as far as the number you're testing). Then just look your number up using binary searching. If you keep the table around, you can incrementally build it up if you later need to look up a higher number.

Gogo dynamic programming. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can do to speed this up:

Instead of starting from 2 and doing `i++`, check if it's even in the beginning first, and if it's not, start at 3 and increment i by two:

```
if (num % 2 == 0) {
   return false;
}
for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(num); i += 2) { ... }
```

Another tip already in this example is to set your upper bound to the square root of your number instead of `num/2`.

One more thing that requires a little bit of setup is to employ a [prime sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to quickly test if your number is prime.

Comment: I do not recommend doing the `i <= sqrt(num)` test every iteration. Instead, store `sqrt(num)` in a variable of type `int` (or `long`, or another integral type), and compare against that in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The Miller-Rabin test is relatively simple to implement, although proving it's correct is much more difficult. Basically, you run this test several times; each time, you pick a random "witness" number between 2 and your number, and run an algorithm. The test will either tell you that your number is definitely composite (not prime) or that it could be prime (with probability 1/4 that it's wrong each time), so if you run the test ten times with ten random witnesses and get "probably prime" every time, chances are less than one in a million that the number is actually composite.

Wikipedia has an implementation in pseudocode at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_test#Algorithm_and_running_time